# Data wrangling from wide to long format with multiple repeating columns of different types

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-wrangling

A dataset describes multiple repeating measurements for multiple clusters, with each measurement-cluster pair contained in a single column. I would like to wrangle the data into a long(er) format, such that one column provides information on the cluster, but each measurement remains in its own column.

```
# Current format
df_wider <- data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  fruit_1 = sample(fruit, size = 5),
  date_1 = sample(seq(as.Date('2020/01/01'), as.Date('2020/05/01'), by="day"), 5),
  number_1 = sample(1:100, 5),
  fruit_2 = sample(fruit, size = 5),
  date_2 = sample(seq(as.Date('2020/01/01'), as.Date('2020/05/01'), by="day"), 5),
  number_2 = sample(1:100, 5),
  fruit_3 = sample(fruit, size = 5),
  date_3 = sample(seq(as.Date('2020/01/01'), as.Date('2020/05/01'), by="day"), 5),
  number_3 = sample(1:100, 5)
)

# Desired format
df_longer <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:5, each = 3),
  cluster = rep(1:3, 5),
  fruit = sample(fruit, size = 15),
  date = sample(seq(as.Date('2020/01/01'), as.Date('2020/05/01'), by="day"), 15),
  number = sample(1:100, 15)
)
```

The real dataset contains up to 25 clusters of 100s of measurements each. I attempted to use `tidyr::gather()` and `tidyr::pivot_longer()` iterated over each measurement, but the resulting intermediate dataframes increased exponentially in size. Attempting to do so in a single `tidyr::pivot_longer()` step is impossible due to the values' being of different class. I am unable to think of a way to vectorize this up to scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df_wider %>% pivot_longer(-id, 
                          names_pattern = "(.*)_(\\d)", 
                          names_to = c(".value", "cluster"))

# A tibble: 15 x 5
      id cluster fruit        date       number
   <int> <chr>   <fct>        <date>      <int>
 1     1 1       olive        2020-04-21     50
 2     1 2       elderberry   2020-02-23     59
 3     1 3       cherimoya    2020-03-07      9
 4     2 1       jujube       2020-03-22     88
 5     2 2       mandarine    2020-03-06     45
 6     2 3       grape        2020-04-23     78
 7     3 1       nut          2020-01-26     53
 8     3 2       cantaloupe   2020-01-27     70
 9     3 3       durian       2020-02-15     39
10     4 1       chili pepper 2020-03-17     60
11     4 2       raisin       2020-04-14     20
12     4 3       cloudberry   2020-03-11      4
13     5 1       honeydew     2020-01-04     81
14     5 2       lime         2020-03-23     53
15     5 3       ugli fruit   2020-01-13     26
```

Comment: It took me longer to write out my problem than it did you to answer it. You were so fast, that stackoverflow won't let me mark it as the correct answer yet. Really impressive, and thank you. I love this site.

Comment: You're welcome ;) You just got lucky because I was actually trying to learn how to play with `names_pattern` so, your question was a really good exercise to me.

Comment: I should have asked this question 20 hours ago, when I first realised this would be a problem for me...

Comment: I think it's always good to try yourself a little bit first ;)You better appreciate and understand the answer then ;)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df_wider), measure = patterns('^fruit', '^date', '^number' ), 
      value.name = c('fruit', 'date', 'number'), variable.name = 'cluster')
#    id cluster        fruit       date number
# 1:  1       1         date 2020-04-16     17
# 2:  2       1       quince 2020-01-27      7
# 3:  3       1      coconut 2020-04-19     33
# 4:  4       1  pomegranate 2020-02-27     55
# 5:  5       1    persimmon 2020-02-20     62
# 6:  1       2   kiwi fruit 2020-01-14    100
# 7:  2       2    cranberry 2020-03-15     97
# 8:  3       2     cucumber 2020-03-16      5
# 9:  4       2    persimmon 2020-03-06     81
#10:  5       2         date 2020-04-17     30
#11:  1       3      apricot 2020-04-13     86
#12:  2       3       banana 2020-04-17     42
#13:  3       3     bilberry 2020-02-23     88
#14:  4       3 blackcurrant 2020-02-25     10
#15:  5       3       raisin 2020-02-09     87
```